# Facebook Graph API - How to read posts privacy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I read the example of Graph API document at this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/privacy/, and try to get the privacy of specified post but no luck. The link I tried is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?fields=value&access_token=<my token>
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (value) on node type (User)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "DSUBZSZdJT8"
  }
}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is very clear, there is no field called "value" in the user table - which is exactly what you are trying to access with the `/me` endpoint. This would be the API call to get the privacy setting of a specific post:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}?fields=privacy{value}&access_token={user-token}
```